# Producer consumer in python locks on get

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I'm struggling to make a producer consumer queue in Python3. I can't get my consumer to wake up:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time
def consumer(q):
        while(True):
            data=q.get()
            if (data[0]==False):
                print("Killing")
                return
            print((data[1]))
            time.sleep(1)

maxitems=3
q = Queue(maxitems)
p = Process(target=consumer, args=(q,))
p.start()
for idx in range(0,10):
    q.put((True,idx))
    #Where idx would normally be a chunk of data
p.put((False,False))
p.join()
```

Output:

```
0
```

then it locks...

How do I get the consumer thread to wake up when I push data to it?

Launch:

```
python3.3 tryit.py
```

Built with:

```
[ebuild   R    ] dev-lang/python-3.3.5-r1:3.3::gentoo  USE="gdbm ipv6 ncurses readline ssl threads xml -build -doc -examples -hardened -sqlite -tk -wininst" 0 KiB
```

Comment: It works fine for me. Are you importing `Queue` from `multiprocessing` or from `queue`?

Comment: It works for me as well using Python 3.4.1. How are you running the script?

Comment: @DavidK I'm using 3.3 running on gentoo. Is there some special things I need?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow this needs to run from **main**

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time
def consumer(q):
         while(True):
            data=q.get()
            if (data[0]==False):
                print("Killing")
                return
            print((data[1]))
            time.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    maxitems=3
    q = Queue(maxitems)
    p = Process(target=consumer, args=(q,))
    p.start()
    for idx in range(0,10):
        q.put((True,idx))
        #Where idx would normally be a chunk of data
    q.put((False,False))
    p.join()
```

Answer (score 0):

`p.put((False,False))` is wrong and some non-idiomatic Python, otherwise it's fine.

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import time

def consumer(q):
        while True:
            data=q.get()
            if data[0]==False:
                print("Killing")
                break
            print(data[1])
            time.sleep(1)

maxitems=3
q = Queue(maxitems)
p = Process(target=consumer, args=(q,))
p.start()
for idx in range(0,10):
    q.put((True,idx))
    #Where idx would normally be a chunk of data
q.put((False,False))
p.join()
```